# Is there any way to prove that if $4y=4x+13k$ then $y=x+13l$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences, congruence-relations

I am doing a true/false problem, and it says if $4y=4x+13k$ then $y=x+13l$. I couldn’t find any counter example so I suppose the statement is true but could not prove the above equation equivalent to $y=x+13l$.

So is the problem true or false?

Thank you

Comment: Use $4\times10\equiv1\pmod{13}$

Comment: The fact that $13$ is prime is incredibly useful here, and essentially ensures that it is "okay to *divide*" in a congruence relation modulo $13$, so we can "*divide*" by $4$ safely from each side.  (*More correctly, it implies that the multiplicative inverse of any number exists so long as it isn't congruent to zero modulo 13.  It is nice to know that the multiplicative inverse of $4$ happens to be $10$, but it isn't necessary to know that explicitly*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt. hint:   using that $\,3 \cdot 4 = 13 - 1\,$, multiplying by $3$ gives:

$$12y=12x+ 3 \cdot 13k \iff 13y - y = 13 x - x + 3 \cdot 13 k \iff y = x - 13 \cdot (x -y + 3k)$$

Answer (score 1):

Given that 
$$4y\equiv 4x\pmod {13}$$
Since $\gcd(4,13)=1$ we have that
$$y\equiv x\pmod {13}\implies y=x+13k\qquad \forall k\in\mathbb{N}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$4x\equiv4y\pmod{13}\implies4x-4y=13k$$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. LHS is divisible by $4$ so $4\mid k$ for the equality to hold. So let $k=4l$, $l\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $$4x-4y=13(4l)\implies x-y=13l\implies x\equiv y\pmod{13}$$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of observations.

(a) multiply by $10$ to obtain $40y=40x+130k$ or $y=x+13(3x-3y+10k)$. Why choose $10$? - Well because $10\times 4 \equiv 1 \bmod 13$, and the multiplicative inverse of $3$ is guaranteed modulo $13$ because $4$ and $13$ are coprime.

(@dxiv's answer uses $3\times 4 \equiv -1 \bmod 13$ in a similar way - note that $10+3=13$ so the multipliers are related)

(b) consider the prime factorisation of $k$ - it must be even, otherwise the left-hand side of the original equation is even and the right-hand side is odd - say $k=2r$. Then divide through by $2$ and note that $r$ is likewise even, say $r=2l$.